# Can we use api in sharepoint 2016 onpremise version?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer

We are trying to integrate API in our SharePoint on-premise 2016 version.
We want to upload files and make folders in the SharePoint on-premise 2016 version using API requests.

In our SharePoint cloud web version, we successfully created a folder and uploaded files using API but the same thing we are trying to do in SharePoint on-premise version but we getting an error in the access token process.

Can anyone tell us if it is possible to make API request in SharePoint on-premise 2016 version?

The error mentioned in this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/308720/trying-to-get-access-token-in-sharepoint-on-premises-2016-but-getting-401-unauth).